# Stack build fails due to missing package although stack ghci works

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I am trying to build a simple program in Haskell using stack. I created a new project using `stack new` and did a `stack setup` after that. The template builds fine.

I want to experiment with binary file parsing, so I imported `Data.ByteString`. My `build-depends` in the cabal file look like this:

```
build-depends:     base >= 4.7 && < 5
                 , bytestring >= 0.10.6
                 , binary >= 0.7.5
```

`stack ghci` now just works, but `stack build` is still not happy. 
Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?

Here is the complete error message:

```
test-0.1.0.0: build
Preprocessing library test-0.1.0.0...
In-place registering test-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'test-exe' for test-0.1.0.0...

haskell/test/app/Main.hs:4:18:
    Could not find module ‘Data.ByteString’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘bytestring-0.10.6.0@bytes_6VWy06pWzJq9evDvK2d4w6’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘bytestring’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

haskell/test/app/Main.hs:5:8:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Binary.Get’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘binary-0.7.5.0@binar_3uXFWMoAGBg0xKP9MHKRwi’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘binary’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

--  While building package test-0.1.0.0 using:
      .stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:test exe:test-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

and this is my app/Main.hs file:

```
module Main where

import Lib
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Binary.Get
import Data.Word

main :: IO ()
main =  do
    putStrLn "f"
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: what is `stack build` complaining about?

Comment: Could not find module ‘Data.ByteString’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘bytestring-0.10.6.0@bytes_6VWy06pWzJq9evDvK2d4w6’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘bytestring’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

    Could not find module ‘Data.Binary.Get’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘binary-0.7.5.0@binar_3uXFWMoAGBg0xKP9MHKRwi’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘binary’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Comment: sorry. I don't know how to format that in a comment

Comment: @draetsch: First of all, you can always [edit] your question to include new information. Second, add the complete content of your cabal-file (minus personal information, but the library/executable/benchmark/test-suite part should be included). Third, post the exact error message, including the line and file where the problem occurred. You're most likely using `ByteString` in your exectuable.

Comment: have you updated your stack.yaml

Comment: @sclv if your question is if I changed the `stack.yaml`, then no. This is just vanilla `stack.yaml` as the `stack new` creates it.

Comment: In that case, you need to add dependencies to your `stack.yaml` as well as your cabal install. Stack doesn't manage its dependencies from the cabal file, but from the stack.yaml file.

Comment: @sclv I added bytestring-0.10.6.0 to my stack.yaml and it does not help. I have tested this on two machines and two operating systems now. I use osx and windows. I don't have problems with lens for example, but bytestring does not work at all.

Comment: Hey, I am really sorry that I bothered you all for a stupid mistake I made while editing my cabal file, that caused this error. I added the build-depends to the library project, not to the executable. I am really sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because you added `bytestring` to the `build-depends` of the library, not the executable.  One option to avoid needing to repeat these dependencies for the different stanzas is to use [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack) as the package description format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I already stated in my last comment, that was really the error. Thank you for pointing me to pack. I will look at it.